# DC.JS Pie Chart + Select Deslect from external JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc.js (http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) Which is a wrapper to d3 and crossfilter.
I want to click the pieChart from dc.js Externally.

http://jsfiddle.net/nishants/Bra2H/47/

```
var hitslineChart  = dc.lineChart("#chart-line-hitsperday");

var data = [
        {date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
        {date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
        ];
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
    d.Year=d.date.getFullYear();
});

var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

hitslineChart
    .width(500).height(200)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(hits)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Hits per day");

var yearRingChart   = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year");
var yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;});
var year_total = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.http_200+d.http_302;});

yearRingChart
.width(150).height(150)
.dimension(yearDim)
.group(year_total)
.innerRadius(30);

dc.renderAll();
```

I could not find a way to click or call cross filter code external to dc.js widgtes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `dc.js` source, the clicks are handled at the chart level in an `_onClick` handler.  So, I'd just call this explicitly.  You'll need to pass in the data element you are "clicking" on:

```
yearRingChart._onClick(yearRingChart.data()[0]);
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bra2H/48/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I seen the _onClick but could not realized it should be use this way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use filters...

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=filter1()>Date Filter</button>
```

*JS*

```
function filter1() {
    yearRingChart.filter('2014');
    dc.redrawAll();
};
```

Comment: I put your filter in here  http://jsfiddle.net/Bra2H/57/  But its causing shade out both 2012 and 2013, Expected behavior is once 2012 selected once unselected on clicking date filter.

Comment: try to remove the quotes around 2012